# How to give my path a property that is in a nested class?

Tags: c#, wpf

So I am having issues with having a datatrigger fire because I cannot seem to set the path to a property in a nested class.  This is what my trigger currently looks like:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Path=Item.ColWarning.HasWarning, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True">
```

And here is the property that I'm trying to access:

```
public class Column {

    public Warning ColWarning = new Warning();

    //other stuff happens in this class

    public class Warning : BaseModel
    {

        private const string ChangedLength = "Column length will also be changed in tables: ";

        public bool HasWarning { get { return _warning == null ? false : true; } }

        private string _warning;

        public string WarningMessage { get { return _warning; } }

        public void ValidateCol(Column col)
        {
            _warning = "something";
            NotifyPropertyChanged("HasWarning");
            //actual validation stuff happens here
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, the Item in the WPF Path refers to the Column.  Also, I know that it works correctly if I get rid of the Warning class and include the properties in the Column Class.  In this case my path changes to Item.HasWarning and it works.  If any light could be shed on this issue I'd appreciate it!

Comment: `ColWarning` is a field. Try making it a property, with {get;set;} and see if it works then. You can't bind to fields, only to properties. You also won't see any changes after the controls populate, because you haven't implemented INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Thanks I will try that.  Also, I just forgot to include the NotifyPropertyChanged in the code but I have implemented it in my solution.

Comment: Cool, you should be good with just the propertification then.

Comment: `return _warning == null ? false : true;` == `return _warning != null;`

Comment: Thanks Ed! It works

Comment: Cool, I put it in an answer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem is that `ColWarning` is a field rather than a property:

```
public Warning ColWarning = new Warning();
```

`Binding` won't bind to fields, only to properties. Given that your binding works for other properties of `Column` via `Item`, the path you've got should work if you redefine `ColWarning` as a property:

```
private Warning _colWarning = new Warning();
public Warning ColWarning {
    get { return _colWarning; }
    set {
        _colWarning = value;
        //  ...or whatever you're doing to raise PropertyChanged
        OnPropertyChanged("ColWarning");
    }
}
```